# Yearly Forecasting in WEKA ,

Tags: forecasting, rweka

[image: error]I am doing timeseries forecasting on energy consumption dataset. i have data in yearly format for 6 years. i have converted my file to csv and installed Forecast package in weka. When i am trying to forecast my Energy column by selecting timestamp and periodicity Year i get following error.
My data is sorted on yearly basis , please guide me what is the issue

My data has following columns Index(['Year', 'Technology Size', 'Final Energy Consumption in TOE',
'Tons of CO2 Eqv. (Metric Ton)', 'Type of Vehicle', 'Fuel', 'Division',
'Province', 'District', 'Country', 'Category', 'Vehicles'],)
I am trying to forecast energy for next 5 years using weka. but i am getting error that data is not in ascending order.